do not Interrupt code having flag set -e in bash script
I got code
#!/bin/bash
set -e
helm status deployment-name
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
  echo "uninstall helm release"
  helm uninstall deployment-name
else 
  echo "helm reease doesnot exist"
fi

helm install ....
So script check if helm release exists, if exists we got 0, if not Error
but if not exists should go through If  and print echo "helm reease doesnot exist" but we have a flag set -e that cause exit/interrupt script.
How should I implement it if the error occurs it will go to else not exit code.
helm version 3.10

Don't use $?, but just put the command in the if itself: if helm status deployment-name; then ....

if helm status deployment-name return non binary output, some text so it is wrong

You can always write set +e.  In fact, you should always write set +e.  Enabling errexit is one of the biggest mistakes you can make when writing a shell script.  See https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/105

@user1666649: output doesn't matter, if only cares about the return status. if echo foo; then ... works just fine (it isn't very useful, though.). Shellcheck also discourages use of $?: https://www.shellcheck.net/wiki/SC2181

See Why is testing "$?" to see if a command succeeded or not, an anti-pattern?.

Please read https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/105  Although in recent years, setting errexit has become popular, it is a mistake to do so.  Explicit is better than implicit, and cmd || exit is better than set -e; cmd
Explicitly checking the value of $? after running a command is not necessary.  When errexit is disabled if cmd; then ... is equivalent to cmd; if [ $? = 0 ] then ....  When errexit is enabled, if cmd; then ... is the same as cmd || : ; if [ $? = 0 ]; then ....  In both cases, the former is preferred.
In other words, you have a few options.  You could simply disable errexit by writing:
 set +e 
 helm status "$deployment_name"
 ...

(or just deleting the set -e, which IMO is the right thing to do, but you may need to make appropriate changes to the rest of your script), or you could do:
if helm status "$deployment_name"; then ...

or:
helm status "$deployment_name" || :
if [ $? = 0 ]; then ...

IMO, the best solution is to delete set -e and edit the rest of the script as necessary.  Friends don't let friends enable errexit.  The worst possible solution is given last; you should never explicitly check the value of $?, except possibly in a case statement where a process returns multiple non-zero values for different error states.

As commented by multiple persons, you should really avoid using set -e.
Anyway, if using it and wanting to also capture exit code of failed command and test it; you may do it like this:
#!/usr/bin/env bash
set -e
rc=0 && helm status deployment-name 2> /dev/null || rc=$?
if [ $rc -eq 0 ]; then
  echo "uninstall helm release"
  helm uninstall deployment-name
else 
  printf 'Return code: %d\n' "$rc"
  echo "helm reease doesnot exist"
fi

Suffixing the command call with || rc=$?, || prevents stopping script on error as the command is now part of a condition. The next part of the OR condition is used to save the exit code with rc=$?
Alternatively you can integrate the call to the command and the $rc assignment directly in the condition with a command group ending with the false command to trigger the false branch of the if like this:
#!/usr/bin/env bash
set -e
if helm status deployment-name 2> /dev/null || { rc=$?;false;}; then
  echo "uninstall helm release"
  helm uninstall deployment-name
else 
  printf 'Return code: %d\n' "$rc"
  echo "helm reease doesnot exist"
fi

